# $http request in ionic app to a simple node server throws "statusText": "" error

Tags: node.js, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've stripped down an $http request to the bones and it's still failing without a helpful error message. Within my Angular factory I have:

```
var url = "http://localhost:3000";
var deferred = $q.defer();

$http.get(url)
  .then(function (success) {
    deferred.resolve(success)
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    deferred.reject(err)
  })
return deferred.promise;
```

Inside my node routes I have:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json({test: 'hi from node index.js'})
});
```

The full error I'm receiving within my ionic app is:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "status": -1,
  "config": {
     "method": "GET",
     "transformRequest": [
        null
     ],
     "transformResponse": [
        null
     ],
  "url": "http://localhost:3000",
  "headers": {
     "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
   }
},
"statusText": ""
```

I've tried to catch the error inside my node server and I receive

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

I've disabled cors within my node app.js. I've tried to make a connection with sockets, but still haven't had any luck. I'm running my ionic app with ionic run.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: We need more code to debug. Somewhere you are trying to access the property `type` of a variable which is undefined. So please post complete route configuration code.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: naturally the device has it's own localhost, so when I'm sending an $http.get request from my ionic app, it's not sending it to the same localhost my node server is running on. The solution is to target your deployed server or your local machine.